# Jacoco multimodule with integration tests - REST Controllers not covered

Tags: spring-boot, maven, code-coverage, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have mutliple layers on an application (web, business...). 
I want to publish coverage of each test (unit and integration tests) on sonar by using `jacoco-maven-plugin`.

In the application, all the code is covered by unit and integration tests, and the `pom.xml` is correct but I have this problem:

The controllers code is not considered to be covered by the tests in jacoco reports, unlike the services (business layer) called by these controllers !

Example :

`FunctionalityAService.java` covered by `FunctionalityAServiceTest.java` (unit test)

`FunctionalityBService.java` covered, `FunctionalityBController.java` not covered by `FunctionalityBControllerIT.java` (integration test)

You can find an example here : https://github.com/salimchami/maven-jacoco-multimodule-sonar

How to include coverage on Controllers ?

EDIT 1 :

I don't understand why it's mandatory to create a module only to aggragate results... Why We can't do this in the root module (jacoco-aggregate directory in the root module) ?

EDIT 2 :

It's a spring boot project and I'm using spring mockMvc in the integration tests.
So, the controllers are not called by an instantiation.

Comment: IMHO, your pom.xml is a bit too light, you should compare this : https://github.com/salimchami/maven-jacoco-multimodule-sonar/blob/master/pom.xml to this : https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/creating-code-coverage-reports-for-unit-and-integration-tests-with-the-jacoco-maven-plugin/

Comment: Thanks. After some fixes, it works now !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution :

Root pom :

```xml
<modules>
    <module>dao</module>
    <module>domain</module>
    <module>web</module>
    <module>coverage</module>
</modules>
 
<properties>
    <project.xmlReportPaths>coverage/target/site/jacoco-aggregate/jacoco.xml</project.xmlReportPaths>
</properties>
 
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0.1746</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*IT.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report-aggregate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
 
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>its</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>integration-test</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>it-agent</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>it-report</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report-integration</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

coverage module pom :

```xml
<properties>
    <sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>${project.basedir}/../${project.xmlReportPaths}
        </sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<!-- list of all sub modules dependencies -->
</dependencies>
```

example of sub module :

```xml
<properties>
    <sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>${project.basedir}/../${project.xmlReportPaths}</sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
</properties>
```

Comment: Where exactly should `@{failsafeArgLine}` be added?

Comment: No need to add the variable. Sorry, I edited the response. Here is the repo where I put the solution : https://github.com/salimchami/maven-jacoco-multimodule-sonar